# How to use SQLalchemy in_ with a list object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I was trying to query a database based on some pre selected items and ran into a weird situation. I started with pre selecting some parameters that I would like use as filter in a query from one of the tables in the database:

```
MX_noaa_numbers = list(Events_df[Events_df['flareclass'].str.contains('M|X')].noaanumber.unique())
```

Which produces a list such as:

```
[11583,11611,11771,11777,11778,11865,12253,11967,11968,...,12673]
```

But when I tried to obtain the results using:

```
session.query(ActiveRegion).filter(sql.or_(ActiveRegion.noaa_number1.in_(MX_noaa_numbers),
                                       ActiveRegion.noaa_number2.in_(MX_noaa_numbers),
                                       ActiveRegion.noaa_number3.in_(MX_noaa_numbers))).all()
```

it returns me an empty list. However if I print `MX_noaa_numbers` and copy the output inside the `in_()` statement substituting the object name (`MX_noaa_numbers`) I actually get the results as I should. Am I missing something or I actually ran into some weird error?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks good. Consider the possibility that your data or even database is not what you think. Double check everything. Other people cannot do much in the way of debugging without the data.

Comment: I will check again. Thanks for clarifying to me my query itself is not wrong.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind from "if I print ... and copy the ouput inside" is that are the numbers Python integers, or are they for example Numpy integers or some such?